# Backporting Python 3 open(encoding="utf-8") to Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a Python codebase, built for Python 3, which uses Python 3 style open() with encoding parameter:

https://github.com/miohtama/vvv/blob/master/vvv/textlineplugin.py#L47

```
    with open(fname, "rt", encoding="utf-8") as f:
```

Now I'd like to backport this code to Python 2.x, so that I would have a codebase which works with Python 2 and Python 3.

What's the recommended strategy to work around `open()` differences and lack of encoding parameter?

Could I have a Python 3 `open()` style file handler which streams bytestrings, so it would act like Python 2 `open()`?

Answer (score 191, accepted):

#### 1. To get an encoding parameter in Python 2:

If you only need to support Python 2.6 and 2.7 you can use [`io.open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) instead of `open`. `io` is the new io subsystem for Python 3, and it exists in Python 2,6 ans 2.7 as well. Please be aware that in Python 2.6 (as well as 3.0) it's implemented purely in python and very slow, so if you need speed in reading files, it's not a good option.

If you need speed, and you need to support Python 2.6 or earlier, you can use [`codecs.open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) instead. It also has an encoding parameter, and is quite similar to `io.open` except it handles line-endings differently.

#### 2. To get a Python 3 `open()` style file handler which streams bytestrings:

```
open(filename, 'rb')
```

Note the 'b', meaning 'binary'.

Comment: The 'b' actually means binary mode, not bytes. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open.

Comment: @pmdarrow Same thing in this case, but strictly speaking, yes.

Comment: I ran into the problem that you cannot run regex over a byte stream for option 2 ;)

Comment: @macmadness86 You need to use a byte regexp expression.

Comment: A note from the porting howto: "Do not bother with the outdated practice of using codecs.open() as that’s only necessary for keeping compatibility with Python 2.5." https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html

Comment: I did a very simple benchmark between `io.open()` and `codecs.open()` in Python 2.7 with `utf-8-sign` encoding on a large file and I was very surprised to find that the former performed much better on my machine than the latter.

Comment: Yes. `codecs` is only faster on Python 2.6 (and possibly on 3.0). With the `encoding=` parameter in `io.open()` you really don't need codecs.open() any more, afaik.

Answer (score 74):

I think

```
from io import open
```

should do.

Comment: I think Lennart's response below is much better as it provides more explanation and the caveat about the io module being slow in 2.x along with the suggestion to use codecs.open.

Comment: What happens if I use `from io import open` in Python 3? I do not care for performance currently.

Comment: @matth In python3 open from io is an alias for the built-in open. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=io#io.open

Answer (score 32):

Here's one way:

```
with open("filename.txt", "rb") as f:
    contents = f.read().decode("UTF-8")
```

Here's how to do the same thing when writing:

```
with open("filename.txt", "wb") as f:
    f.write(contents.encode("UTF-8"))
```

Comment: this obviously does not work if you had different plans for `f`

Comment: Exactly, what if you want to write to this file instead of reading?

Comment: @Orb I've edited my answer post to answer your question.

Comment: Note that `contents` in this answer post is a string in Python 3 (it's a Unicode string in Python 2).

Answer (score 9):

This may do the trick:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] > 2:
    # py3k
    pass
else:
    # py2
    import codecs
    import warnings
    def open(file, mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None,
             errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True, opener=None):
        if newline is not None:
            warnings.warn('newline is not supported in py2')
        if not closefd:
            warnings.warn('closefd is not supported in py2')
        if opener is not None:
            warnings.warn('opener is not supported in py2')
        return codecs.open(filename=file, mode=mode, encoding=encoding,
                    errors=errors, buffering=buffering)
```

Then you can keep you code in the python3 way.

Note that some APIs like `newline`, `closefd`, `opener` do not work

Comment: you can reverse the condition to avoid that `pass`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [`six`](https://six.readthedocs.io/), you can try this, by which utilizing the latest Python 3 API and can run in both Python 2/3:

```py
import six

if six.PY2:
    # FileNotFoundError is only available since Python 3.3
    FileNotFoundError = IOError
    from io import open

fname = 'index.rst'
try:
    with open(fname, "rt", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        pass
        # do_something_with_f ...
except FileNotFoundError:
    print('Oops.')
```

And, Python 2 support abandon is just deleting everything related to `six`.

Answer (score 1):

Not a general answer, but may be useful for the specific case where you are happy with the default python 2 encoding, but want to specify utf-8 for python 3:

```
if sys.version_info.major > 2:
    do_open = lambda filename: open(filename, encoding='utf-8')
else:
    do_open = lambda filename: open(filename)

with do_open(filename) as file:
    pass
```