# I am getting a UnicodeDecodeError when using Jupyter Lab

Tags: error-handling, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Jupyter Lab is not running on my computer even though all the code is correct. It keeps showing "Unicode Decode Error"

Jupyter Lab is showing me this error. I have tried to look it up online but the only references I can find are to pandas module, and I am not using Pandas. The code is correct, but I keep receiving this Unicode Decode Error on my end, for whatever reason.
I am using a Notebook in .ipynb format.
Please look into this. I am very grateful[This is a screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5sr3.png) for your response.

Comment: You are using Python. It happens to be in JupyterLab but that is tangential to this issue. In other words title should be 'using Python in JupyterLab' or just 'using Python'.  Jupyter runs lots of language kernels. Topic/Category keywords should include Python and not just Jupyter. In this case it would help you know where to look for help to keep things straight. For your Python issue, you need to set the `encoding` in your `open` statement, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16529599/8508004) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39001821/8508004).