# Python encoding issue (possibly from windows to linux issue)

Tags: python, linux, csv, encoding

I am working on a program which was written in python under windows. It is reading cvs file. Here is the part of the code:

```
with open(os.path.abspath(self.currencies_file_path), 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    #for each row find whether such isocode exists in the table
    for row in reader:   #THis is line 49
```

And this is the error:

```
  File "whatever/staticdata.py", line 49, in upload_currencies
    for row in reader:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/codecs.py", line 313, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 1307: invalid continuation byte
```

The csv file is not even encoded with utf-8(I think). Why am I having this kind of issue?

P.S. I dont know anything about encodings.

Comment: Do you know the encoding file was written with?

Comment: @user590028 I dont know, is there a way to determine it ?

Comment: I think it is latin1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check the file encoding, you can use the file command:

```
$ file utils.py
utils.py: Python script, UTF-8 Unicode text executable
```

To convert a file, you can use the iconv command:

```
iconv -f ascii -t utf-8 utils.py -o utils.utf8.py
```

Options: `-f`: from-encoding; `-t`: to-encoding; `-o` outputfile.

Last but not least, explicitly declare the encoding (at the top right below the shebang):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

So, for a working example, you would have something like:

```
#/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

For a list of encoding supported by iconv, you can type:

```
iconv -l
```

Comment: This is my cvs file: `data/currencies.csv: ISO-8859 text`  Why am i having this kind of problems?

Comment: Windows and linux use different default encodings. It's usually UTF-8 on Linux. I am pretty sure you don't have an encoding line in your script (the line that starts with `# -*- coding` . If you don't tell python which one you use, I think it uses ascii by default. There might be different fallbacks on linux and windows. But it's a good idea to be explicit and tell it exactly what it is

Comment: Oh wait a second, you're talking about a CSV file, and not a python file. Still use the iconv command to convert it though.

Comment: So python is trying utf-8 by default and that is the reason it doesn't work?

Comment: It must be using either the `locale` (usually utf-8) or utf-8 by default. But reading a csv file is using the same process as launching a python script, it uses the locale by default

Comment: Found a "ó" in cvs, that is where it fails.

Comment: It did, I will accept your answer but one thing: the flag for output is not `-i` but `-o`

Comment: According to the `man`: `--output, -o file Specify output file (instead of stdout).`

Answer (score 2):

If you think it's latin-1, try this:

```
import io
with io.open(os.path.abspath(self.currencies_file_path), encoding='latin-1') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows is probably using CP-1252.

There is no way to know, 100% of the time, which encoding a file is using, see [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436220/python-is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-encoding-of-text-file) for reference.  If you are using Python3 , just specify the encoding to use when opening the file.  If you're using Python 2, you can [use io.open to specify an encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971033/backporting-python-3-openencoding-utf-8-to-python-2) to use.