# TypeError: must be unicode, not str in NLTK

Tags: python, nltk, crf

I am using python2.7, nltk 3.2.1 and python-crfsuite 0.8.4.  I am following this page : http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tag.html?highlight=stanford#nltk.tag.stanford.NERTagger for nltk.tag.crf module.

To start with i just run this

```
from nltk.tag import CRFTagger
ct = CRFTagger()
train_data = [[('dfd','dfd')]]
ct.train(train_data,"abc")
```

I tried this too

```
f = open("abc","wb")
ct.train(train_data,f)
```

but i am getting the following error,

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\crf.py", line 129, in <genexpr>
    if all (unicodedata.category(x) in punc_cat for x in token):
TypeError: must be unicode, not str
```

Comment: Can you show us the data in "abc"? There lies your problem, according to the error...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Python 2, regular quotes `'...'` or `"..."` create byte strings. To get Unicode strings, use a `u` prefix before the string, like `u'dfd'`.

To read from a file, you'll want to specify an encoding. See [Backporting Python 3 `open(encoding="utf-8")` to Python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971033/backporting-python-3-openencoding-utf-8-to-python-2) for options; most straightforwardly, replace `open()` with `io.open()`.

To convert an existing string, use the `unicode()` method; though usually, you'll want to use `decode()` and supply an encoding, too.

For (much) more details, Ned Batchelder's "Pragmatic Unicode" slides are recommended, if not outright obligatory reading; http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html