# Korean txt file encoding with utf-8

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to process a Korean text file with python, but it fails when I try to encode the file with utf-8.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-


f = open('tag.txt', 'r', encoding='utf=8')
s = f.readlines()

z = open('tagresult.txt', 'w')
y = z.write(s)
z.close
```

> ```
> =============================================================
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\******\Desktop\tagging.py", line 5, in <module>
>     f = open('tag.txt', 'r', encoding='utf=8')
> TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
> [Finished in 0.1s]
>
> ==================================================================
> ```

And when I just opens a Korean txt file encoded with utf-8, the fonts are broken like this. What can I do?

> \xc1\xc1\xbe\xc6\xc1\xf6\xb4\xc2\n',
>   '\xc1\xc1\xbe\xc6\xc7\xcf\xb0\xc5\xb5\xe7\xbf\xe4\n',
>   '\xc1\xc1\xbe\xc6\xc7\xcf\xbd\xc3\xb4\xc2\n',
>   '\xc1\xcb\xbc\xdb\xc7\xd1\xb5\xa5\xbf\xe4\n',
>   '\xc1\xd6\xb1\xb8\xbf\xe4\

Comment: Can you tell us if it is Python 2 or 3?

Comment: I use python 2 and it doesn't work if I correct the typo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Backporting Python 3 open(encoding="utf-8") to Python 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971033/backporting-python-3-openencoding-utf-8-to-python-2)

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2 the [open function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) does not take an encoding parameter. Instead you read a line and convert it to unicode. This [article](https://pythonhosted.org/kitchen/unicode-frustrations.html) on kitchen (as in kitchen sink) modules provides details and some lightweight utilities to work with unicode in python 2.x.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Korean, and don't have sample string to try, but here are some advices for you:

1

```
f = open('tag.txt', 'r', encoding='utf=8')
```

You have a typo here, `utf-8` not `utf=8`, this explains for the exception you got.

The default mode of `open()` is 'r' so you don't have to define it again.

2 Don't just use `open`, you should use [context manager](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) statement to manage the opening/closing file descriptor, like this:

```
with open('tagresult.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(s)
```