# Python: encoding a file as you write it

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, encode

I'm using python 2.7 and I'm trying to write a file with some encoding (in my 'finalList' variable the encoding is: 0xe9)

This is how I'm trying to write my file using the 'json' and 'io' modules

```
import json
import io

with io.open('my.json', 'w', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
    json.dump(finalList, outfile)
```

Comment: I bet you're running python 2.

Comment: Yes, I just updated the post to say I'm using 2.7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Backporting Python 3 open(encoding="utf-8") to Python 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971033/backporting-python-3-openencoding-utf-8-to-python-2)

Comment: just found some answer for you.

Comment: You're not using `codecs` at all.

Comment: Where did you get `io` from?

Comment: I just added it from the example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971033/backporting-python-3-openencoding-utf-8-to-python-2 ..but now I'm getting this error: name 'io' is not defined

Comment: You need to `import io` to use `io.open()`, or `import codecs` and use `codecs.open()`. Both should work. Or better, use the answer jcomeau_ictx suggests.

Comment: I'm not using io.open and changed my code in my question...but getting this error: json.dump(finalList, outfile)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 190, in dump
    fp.write(chunk)
TypeError: must be unicode, not str

Answer (score 1):

`json.dump` accepts an `encoding` arg which defaults to 'utf-8':

```
$ pydoc json.dump
Help on function dump in json:

json.dump = dump(obj, fp, skipkeys=False, ensure_ascii=True, check_circular=True, allow_nan=True, cls=None, indent=None, separators=None, encoding='utf-8', default=None, sort_keys=False, **kw)
```

Comment: Using python 3.4: `json.dump(dict(),io.StringIO(),encoding='utf-8')` gives me: `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'`

Comment: the question is tagged python2.7