# Python encoding problem when reading but not when typing

Tags: python

I'm reading some strings from a text file.
Some of these strings have some "strange" characters, e.g. "\xc3\xa9comiam".
If I copy that string and paste it into a variable, I can convert it to readable characters:

```py
string = "\xc3\xa9comiam"
print(string.encode("raw_unicode_escape").decode('utf-8'))
écomiam
```

but if I read it from the file, it doesn't work:

```py
with open(fn) as f:
       for string in f.readlines():
          print(string.encode("raw_unicode_escape").decode('utf-8'))
\xc3\xa9comiam
```

It seems the solution must be pretty easy, but I can't find it.
What can I do?

Thanks!

Comment: if you open with an encoding parameter, do you have the same issue? `open(fn, encoding="utf-8")`

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971033/backporting-python-3-openencoding-utf-8-to-python-2

Comment: Does the file contain the characters `\xc3\xa9comiam` in ASCII or the characters `écomiam`?

Comment: Yes, nickthefreak, I have the same problem and I can't solve it with the solution proposed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971033/backporting-python-3-openencoding-utf-8-to-python-2.

Comment: cdarke, if I open the file with a text editor (sublime), I see the ASCII characters (\xc3\xa9comiam)

Comment: Just to be certain, you have the characters \ then `x` , then `3`, etc., so the file is not actually in utf8 format?

Comment: Yes, cdarke.
I think I've fixed it with a simple replacement:
```string.replace('\\','').encode("raw_unicode_escape").decode('utf-8')```

Comment: Your first code snippet doesn't work for me, are you using Python 2 or something?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020539/process-escape-sequences-in-a-string-in-python

Comment: I'm using python 3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help,

I think, I've found a solution (not very elegant, but it does the trick).

```py
print(bytes(tm.strip(), "utf-8").decode("unicode_escape").encode("raw_unicode_escape").decode('utf-8'))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Those not `unicode-escape` ones - like the name suggests, that handles Unicode sequences like `\u00e9` but not `\xe9`.

What you have is a UTF-8 enooded sequence. The way to decode that is to get it into a `bytes` sequence which can then be decoded to a Unicode string.

```
# Let's not shadow the string library
s = "\xc3\xa9comiam"
print(bytes(s, 'latin-1').decode('utf-8'))
```

The `'latin-1'` trick is a dirty secret which simply converts every byte to a character with the same character code.

For your file, you could open it in binary mode so you don't have to explictly convert it to `bytes`, or you could simply apply the same conversion to the strings you read.

Comment: Thanks tripleee, but it doesn't work for me. However, I've found a solution based on your suggestion.