# Reading files with special characters and writing them to html

Tags: python

I have a python script that reads the names of pdf files and writes them to an HTML file with links to the PDFs. All works well unless a name has special characters.

I have read many other answers on SE to no avail.

```
f = open("jobs/index.html", "w")
#html divs go here
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('jobs/'):
    files.sort()
    for name in files:
        if ((name!="index.html")&(name!=".htaccess")):
            f.write("<a href='"+name+"'>"+name.rstrip(".pdf")+"</a>\n<br><br>\n")
            print name.rstrip(".pdf")
```

Returns:
Caba�n-Sanchez, Jane.pdf
Smith, John.pdf

Which is of course breaks the text and the link to that pdf.

**How can I correctly encode the file or 'name' variable so that it writes special characters correctly?**
ie, Cabán-Sanchez, Jane.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I'm not used to python 2.7, but this should work:

```
from io import open

with open("jobs/index.html", "w", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('jobs/'):
        files.sort()
        for name in files:
            if not name in ("index.html", ".htaccess"):
                f.write("<a href='{}'>{}</a>\n<br><br>\n".format(name, name.rstrip(".pdf")))
                print name.rstrip(".pdf")
```

You should also declare your encoding at a python level, by adding these lines at the top of your module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

And finally, you may try to explicitly declare your string as unicode by adding a `u""` your `f.write` line, like:

```
f.write(u"...")
```

> - Why `io.open`: [Backporting Python 3 open(encoding="utf-8") to Python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971033/backporting-python-3-openencoding-utf-8-to-python-2)
> - Why you should use the `with` keyword when you can: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/with-statement-in-python

Comment: TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function. I don't think encoding is supported in 2.7

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 3: ordinal not in range(128) on the f.write line... I'm kind of going around in circles between a few SO solutions and errors...

Comment: I guess you can not switch to python3? encoding is a plague with python2.x... However, see my upcoming update

Comment: Unfortunately no, its packaged with GIS, which depends on 2.7. using utf-9 it forces me to use u'..' I have also declared utf-8 at top... Thanks

Comment: If you could switch to QGis3+ you would also get python3... But anyway, did it worked for you? Is your problem solved? If it is, could you consider marking the answer as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to write a unicode character (`á` in this case) to a html file, you should specify the html [meta charset](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_charset.asp).

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

The rest of it works fine in my machine though

```
andraantariksa@LaptopnyaAndra:~$ cd Desktop/
andraantariksa@LaptopnyaAndra:~/Desktop$ mkdir jobs
andraantariksa@LaptopnyaAndra:~/Desktop$ cd jobs/
andraantariksa@LaptopnyaAndra:~/Desktop/jobs$ touch "Cabán-Sanchez, Jane.pdf"
andraantariksa@LaptopnyaAndra:~/Desktop/jobs$ ls
'Cabán-Sanchez, Jane.pdf'
andraantariksa@LaptopnyaAndra:~/Desktop/jobs$ cd ../
andraantariksa@LaptopnyaAndra:~/Desktop$ python
Python 2.7.15+ (default, Nov 27 2018, 23:36:35) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> f = open("jobs/index.html", "w")
>>> #html divs go here
... for root, dirs, files in os.walk('jobs/'):
...     files.sort()
...     for name in files:
...         if ((name!="index.html")&(name!=".htaccess")):
...             f.write("<a href='"+name+"'>"+name.rstrip(".pdf")+"</a>\n<br><br>\n")
...             print name.rstrip(".pdf")
... 
Cabán-Sanchez, Jane
andraantariksa@LaptopnyaAndra:~/Desktop$ cat jobs/index.html 
<a href='Cabán-Sanchez, Jane.pdf'>Cabán-Sanchez, Jane</a>
<br><br>
```

Comment: This all looks good to me, I'm not sure why its not working on my end... I have <meta charset="UTF-8"> at the top of my html...