# python encoding issue only in cloud but not on-prem with python version on 2.7.5 on-prem and 2.7.18 on cloud

Tags: python, cloud

Below is the piece of code where it is writing from already encoded cp1252 files.

```
    with open(out_path, "a") as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file, dialect='excel', lineterminator='\n')
        writer.writerows(csv_values)
```

I am getting data as ? in place of -

I have tried to encode to cp1252 again, but getting below error

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 64: ordinal not in range(128)

Later I tried to decode and encode
but then getting subsequent errors.

Strangely this issue is not seen on-prem and on cloud.

Does the python version impact in encoding ?

Comment: Why are you not passing the encoding to `open()`? It works on your computer because you have windows and it fails in the cloud because every other system defaults to urf-8

Comment: but the python code is currently in python2 version and I suppose adding encoding in open supports only from python 3 version

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Backporting Python 3 open(encoding="utf-8") to Python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971033/backporting-python-3-openencoding-utf-8-to-python-2)

Comment: Not really. I see the same issue can be seen in 2.7.5 version in aws server. Something related to cloud env is impacting is what I feel